How do I make a TY vs LY (this year vs last year) comparison table in pandas
Need to create a dynamic table to show source data as TY and LY but my source has data starting 2022. I can get a user input and consider it as "This Year" and take just the last year data. Here is a sample data:
enter image description here
If my user input is 2023 - I need to project the data as 2023 vs 2022, if input is 2024, it would be 2024 vs 2023. But I am not sure how to handle if user input is 2022.
I am a beginner in python, I could not think of a way to achieve this in pandas. I have done this in excel using dropdown and selected values in dropdown
